# Most common text in Excel column

Tags: string, excel, text

I have a list of about 1000 product ids and would like to find those that appear most frequently.

Example:

```
f54
f66
f54
f77
f64
f54
f66
f54
f23
```

And the results would be:

```
f54
f66
f64
f24
```

This will be done in either Excel 2010 (MAC) or LibreOffice.

Comment: welcome to stack over flow!! please mark up the answers that are helpful and click on the checkmark to accept an answer

Comment: thank you! please mark up as well

Comment: Karolis, I suggest you use a pivot table.  This is exactly what they've for, summarizing data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's what you do...

```
+-----+-----+---+
|  A  |  B  | C |
+-----+-----+---+
| f54 | f54 | 4 |
| f66 | f66 | 3 |
| f54 | f54 | 3 |
| f77 | f77 | 2 |
| f64 | f64 | 2 |
| f54 | f23 | 2 |
| f66 |     |   |
| f54 |     |   |
| f23 |     |   |
+-----+-----+---+
```

column `A` is your source column.

column `B` are all the distinct values of column `A`, this is how you do it if you dont know how: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-HP010073943.aspx

C1 will be:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A9,B1)
```

C2:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A9,B2)
```

C3:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A9,B3)
...
```