# Excel: Get most common textual value in a range that has blanks without helper columns or VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to return the most frequently occurring textual value from a range while working within the following parameters:

1. No helper columns (so [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422718/most-common-text-in-excel-column) and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241878/return-most-common-2nd-most-common-3rd-most-common-etc-text-string-in-an-exc) don't work).
2. No VBA (so [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54926474/function-to-find-2nd-and-3rd-most-common-text-string-where-blank-cells-are-prese) doesn't work).
3. The number of values in the range will vary.
4. The range will usually include a number of blank values (so [this solution](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/most-frequently-occurring-word.html) doesn't work).

It seems that every which way I turn, I run into a roadblock. How to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was writing out this question, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47476260/1652620) to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472785/mode-text-2nd-most-common-text-value/), which included this formula:

```
=INDEX(MyList,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(MyList,MyList)),COUNTIF(MyList,MyList),0))
```

And sure enough, that did the trick: no VBA, no helper columns, and no issue with blanks. I was able to replace `MyList` with a range like `D2:D500` and it worked fine.

Comment: Have you tried pivot tables and the included count feature?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't make use of pivot tables in this case either.